# Social Network data sets that contains a community structure

Tags: social-networking, cluster-analysis, spectral

I am working on a set of spectral clustering methods that can essentially be used to detect a community structure in a social network. I tried this on a very small data set (Zachary's Karate club) that was available to me. I am looking out for some large networks where I can check the performance of the algorithm. 
I tried looking the SNAP(snap.stanford.edu) but not getting a data set that contains a well defined community structure. 
Is there any data set which I can use for my purpose?

Comment: Have you found out any large data sets with community structure?

Answer (score 0):

The 'Social Network Analysis Interactive Dataset Library' at http://www.growmeme.com/sna/visual has over 150 datasets, and an ability to filter by size and whether community information is present (among other things).

[image]